# Simple Derivative $\frac{x}{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus

Okay,
I have find the derivative of $$\frac{x}{\ln x}$$ so I used the quotient rule and got: $$\frac{\ln x(1)-x(\frac{1}{x})}{(\ln x)^2}$$

I then simplified this to: $$\frac{-x}{\ln x}.$$

Now here come the problem, when I put $e$ into $f'(x)$ I am supposed to get $-1.5271$ and I do not and I cannot figure out why.  Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Be careful.  You cannot simplify as you have.  The log terms do not cancel.  It is not true that $\frac{a-b}{a^2}=\frac{-b}{a}$.  Try it with a few numbers to see why.

Comment: Isn't your numerator $ \ \ln x - 1 \ $ , making your derivative $ \frac{(\ln x) - 1}{(\ln x)^2} \ $?

Comment: Be careful: is $ln x^2$ the same as  $[\ln(x)]^2$ or $ln(x^2)$?

Comment: I see my mistake straight away and  I feel pretty stupid, thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: Just a note, "derive" is not the same as "take the derivative," at least in most English usage of which I am aware.

Comment: I did a quick edit and changed that. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 
$$ {\ln(x) - 1\over (\ln(x))^2}.$$
The $\ln(x)\cdot 1$ parses to $\ln(x)$.

Comment: But if I put $e$ into that I get zero right? $ln(e) -1 =0$ and zero divided by anything equals zero.

Answer (score 2):

You incorrectly cancelled during your last step.  It is *not true* that $$\frac{ab+c}{a^2}=\frac{b+c}{a}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer you were given is wrong.

$f'(e) = 0$.

Plot it and see.